# Trying to call function from JNI, but I get No implementation found

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, ndk-build

I'm trying to call a native function using ndk/jni but I get this exception

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for java.lang.String 
com.raya.aman.ToolModule.stringFromJNI() (tried Java_com_raya_aman_ToolModule_stringFromJNI and 
Java_com_raya_aman_ToolModule_stringFromJNI__)
```

this is the Java class

```
package com.raya.aman;
public class ToolModule {
public native String stringFromJNI();
static {
    System.loadLibrary("nljnitest");
}
}
```

this is the native function

```
jstring Java_com_raya_aman_ToolModule_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject  obj) {
   char * hello = "Hello from Native";
  return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, hello);
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE        := nljnitest
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES    += $(LOCAL_PATH)/
LOCAL_SRC_FILES     +=  FieldTest.c  log.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS        += -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_ABI :=  armeabi-v7a arm64-v8a
APP_CFLAGS += -Wno-error=format-security
```

I added this to my gradle

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
    }
}
```

[this is my file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xAAT.png)

[jni files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L739T.png)

Comment: Your C function is not declared correctly. Instead of just `jstring` it should be `JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL`.

Comment: Also, you should get rid of `NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9` since GCC is no longer supported by the NDK.

Comment: @Michael i changed to JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL but i get the same exception note that i took this functions from a working demo

Comment: @Michael i removed NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9 from Application.mk but the same issue

Comment: Instead of trying to use some example that might be really old, why don't you just use Android Studio's project wizard to create a new project with C++ support enabled and use that as a template? Or look at one of Google's own NDK examples: https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/master/hello-jni

Answer (score 0):

Is the function in a .cpp/.cxx file by any chance?

Declare as

```
extern "C" string Java_com_raya_aman_ToolModule_stringFromJNI(JNIEnv* env, jobject  obj)
```

Otherwise, the exported function name is mangled according to C++ rules.

Comment: Check the exports of your library with readelf -s (readelf is under `NDK\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin`). If your function there?